# Composed looks don't work anymore

Tags: composed-looks

Composed looks for one SharePoint 2013 site don't work anymore.
Whatever custom look I choose I get the standard blue color for the suitebar

[image]

It's like url theme and even url background image are not working.

What may be the problem?

Comment: How do you customize it? Do you choose any theme or make custom master page?

Comment: even with a standard theme and seattle master page I cannot set the url image or theme.

Comment: what I see is that the memory usage is  over 95%. I should get an upgrade by this evening. Maybe that could be the reason?